# Remove/Disable "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu"

Tags: menus, themes

Is there any way to disable or remove the "Auto add pages - Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" functionality via a theme?

I suppose I could hide it with a bit of CSS, but I'd rather do more cleanly if possible.

Many clients click that not realizing what it does and chaos ensues.

Comment: There is no filter/action to remove it. You can use CSS/JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no filter to remove this option, your best best to to stick to using CSS by putting the following in your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_225635_menu_css' );
function wpse_225635_menu_css() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'nav-menus.php' ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        .auto-add-pages {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comments and [verifiable in the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/788c3680f90b7570f8f9b5277f5d6bf57d7d9209/wp-admin/nav-menus.php#L801):

```
<dl class="auto-add-pages">
    <dt class="howto"><?php _e( 'Auto add pages' ); ?></dt>
    <dd class="checkbox-input"><input type="checkbox"<?php checked( $auto_add ); ?> name="auto-add-pages" id="auto-add-pages" value="1" /> <label for="auto-add-pages"><?php printf( __('Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu' ), esc_url( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ) ) ); ?></label></dd>
</dl>
```

there is no filter to get rid of Auto Add Pages in a clean way. You'll have to use css or javascript.

Comment: ps: we can get the canonical links on GitHub by pressing 'y' - a trick I learned from @toscho